# Is there a Way to save Ckeditor datas through PHP , without JS?

Tags: php, ckeditor

Here i am creating an email editor template.  for that template creations i used CKEditor to create templates. Here is my code.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    //echo  $_POST['message'];   }   ?>
```

and the script here.

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'message');
//]]>
</script>
```

and my HTML code here.

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <textarea class="for_set_height" id="message" name="message" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
    <i class="icon-book on-left"></i>
    <span>Cancel</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

and is it possible to save the Ckeditor datas directly using php  form submissions.

Comment: YES you can do it normally.

Comment: but its  not working for me. i thought it may not

Comment: CHECK THIS LINK:- http://events.manzwebdesigns.com/2011/10/28/saving-ckeditor-data-mysql-database/

Comment: OR you can take help from this also:- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata

Comment: its saves the default value which is there in the textarea.  which is not on ckeditor

Comment: It should be the same as doing normally, just make sure the id matches the field name, (I'd store the data as a tinyblob)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i dont know why its not working.  but i found a way to do it.

Here is my js to save it.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('message');  editor.on( 'change', function( evt ) {      $('[name="message"]').val(evt.editor.getData());});
```

hope it will help someone else.